# Visual Studio 2012 Designer Exception

Tags: .net, visual-studio

For some reason I'm getting an exception when attempting to open/edit a form at design time. (The typical "Ignore and Continue" exception dialog is showing up)

Here is the scenario.
I have a project dll library along with another WindowsForm project in the same solution.  References are correct (at least I'm pretty sure they are).

When I set the Build Configuration to x64, I get the design time exception when opening a Form with any control from the referenced library.  Both projects are set to x64 and I verified both projects platform time in configuration.

When I set the Build Configuration to Any CPU everything is fine.

When I set the Build Configuration to x86 Everything is fine.

I can Debug any of the configurations and the WindowsForm project runs fine.

Is there some issue with Design Time GUI when on x64 platform configuration?

**Exception Details:**

> "Could not find type SimGenGpsSyncLib.Controls.ClockControl". Please
>   make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If
>   this type is part of your development project, make sure that the
>   project has been successfully built using settings for your current
>   platform or Any CPU.
>
> Instances of this error (1)
>   1. There is no stack trace on error line information available for this error.

Note: SimGenGpsSyncLib is obviously the library that has the control.  The project is referenced correctly as simply changing the configuration platform to x86 or Any CPU will allow Design Time edit of the Form containing the control.

The control is a UserControl and was drag/dropped onto the form.

Comment: What are the details/inner exception of the exception?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've added the exception detail.  It's really not much due to it being a Design Time exception.